# Timer doesn't "loop"

Tags: c#, timer

Alright so here is the deal. I am trying to make a application that's a GUI application yet has no GUI. So when the application starts, it has a small form with a login screen (I have done this part).

This the code for the `main()` in which the form runs but as soon as it is closed, I dispose of it.

```
static void Main() 
{       
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);                        
    //Create an instance of form1
    Form1 form1 = new Form1();          
    Application.Run(form1);

    if(form1.isLoggedIn) 
    {             
        filename = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData), DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyhhmm") + "-" + form1.username);
        Flow palm = new Flow(new FlowArguments(form1.username, filename));
        MessageBox.Show("Thankyou, exiting...");
        form1.Dispose();                
    } 
}
```

So as you can see after the form is closed, the main continues on the condition if someone is logged in. If you look carefully, there's a instance to the `Flow` class that's created.

This is a very short class and here we go:

```
public class Flow 
{
    //global variables
    FlowArguments FlowArgs;
    System.Threading.Timer tm;

    //constructor
    public Flow(FlowArguments fmg) 
    {
        FlowArgs = fmg;

        tm = new System.Threading.Timer(Tick, null, 
                                            System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite, 10000);


        using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(FlowArgs.Filename)) 
        {            
            //sw.writelines that SO doesnt really care for.               
        }

        //enable the timer
        tm.Change(0, 100);
    }

    public void Tick(object State) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello");
        //a bunch of SteamWriter writeline methods that SO doesnt care for.
    }

    public void WriteProcesses(StreamWriter sw, DateTime dw) 
    {
        var localAll = Process.GetProcesses().Where(o => o.ProcessName.ToLower() != "svchost");
        foreach(Process p in localAll) 
        {
            sw.WriteLine("@" + p.ProcessName +
                         "[" + dw.ToString("ddMMyyhhmm") + "]" +
                         "[" + FlowArgs.Username + "]");
        }              
    }
}
```

As you can see I do start the timer. But since this uses `System.Threading.Timer` (because I read somewhere that the `Form.Timer` really isn't appropriate) it runs on a threadpool (as per MSDN) but while this is happening the main form has now exited out of `Main()` and hence the program is closed.

What are my possible solutions? This timer will run every 10 minutes (grabbing the processes). After the GUI is closed, I plan on making a system icon tray that the user can use to close the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make the foreground thread wait you can use a WaitHandle.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.waithandle.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Drop all that thread stuff and do it all in a form that implements the system tray icon.  Put your timer in that form and everything you want is done.

Something like

```
LoginForm login = new LoginForm();
if(login.ShowDialog()==DialogResult.OK)
{
    Application.Run(new SystemTrayForm());
}
```

Comment: I would but I am trying to dispose of memory fast. This is because this program is going to be running in the background while a full screen game is playing.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, that's what I need so this is what I've implemented:

```
if(form1.isLoggedIn) {             
    //Create a wait handle for the UI thread.
    AutoResetEvent hold = new AutoResetEvent(false);

    filename = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData), DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyhhmm") + "-" + form1.username);
    Flow palm = new Flow(new FlowArguments(form1.username, filename), hold);

    //wait for the background thread to finish.
    hold.WaitOne(Timeout.Infinite);

    MessageBox.Show("Thankyou, exiting...");
    form1.Dispose();                
}
```

As you see it passes a reference of the AutoResetEvent (from MSDN Timer Class example) to the constructor of the Flow class. From there i can call the "set" method to release the waiting thread. I understand that now.

however

```
hold.WaitOne(Timeout.Infinite);
```

waits for indefinate time.. i'd like to send a "command" to the Flow class to stop the timer and call the "set" method on the waithandle so that the UI thread can exit..

how do I send a "signal"..

NOTE: I have NOT decided where I am gonna put the System Tray icon. So if its easier for me to put it in the Flow class I'd do it.